# Is it possible to delete last n records of a django model in one/minimum database query?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework, orm

I'm trying to delete last 10 records of Task table/model in django but I'm unable to do that in one query.

```
Task.objects.filter(type='Active').order_by('-id')[:10].delete()
```

Above code gives me error **AttributeError : 'list' object has no attribute 'delete'**.
If I make a loop and then use .delete() on each object of that list then it will call db n times which I don't want, is there any other way?

Comment: `Task.objects.filter(id__in=Task.objects.filter(type='Active').order_by('-id').values('id')[:10]).delete()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the primary keys in the queryset to filter with `pk__in=…`:

```
Task.objects.filter(
    pk__in=Task.objects.filter(type='Active').order_by('-id').values('pk')[:10]
).delete()
```

Comment: this is not 1 query to the database. it's not thread safe. Only raw sql can do this thread safe

Comment: @Inventor: no, it is in fact three at least. One to get the `Task`s, one then to retrieve the `Task`s, then one to delete these, and additionally, since Django manages triggers itself, it can result in a lot of extra fetches and removals.

Comment: @Inventor: using raw queries though would probably only be worse, especially since for example one can write custom `on_delete` triggers that would for example conditionally set things to a different value for example. Raw queries are therefore likely bad code design, since these could completely work against what the model intends. Usually views are wrapped in transactions to make the edits atomically. The ideal of Django (and Python) is therefore not to get the most out of a CPU, but mainly to offer programmer convenience.

Comment: I understand, but if you have race condition, you don't have other choice, only raw sql, it's django architecture problem. Transactions do not guarantee thread safety. Only table locks can guarantee, but it is very slow

Comment: @Inventor: but using raw queries, even if we set aside things like the dialect, would simply let the models work not in the intended way. It would not process triggers, in fact if something refers to a `Task`, and we delete tasks, one would want it to cascade, or protect, or whatever, it will not, and thus error. These tickets are open for a very long time, and unfortunately most eventually die: https://github.com/django/django/pull/16851

Comment: @Inventor: as for the race condition, imagine that we don't have any foreignkeys referring to the task, it will first pull the `Task`s, and then make a `DELETE FROM task WHERE id IN (1,2,3)` for example. Now if in the meantime such task is deleted through another thread, that is no problem, since the `IN` does not require that the task is there, if in the meantime another task is created, that will indeed not be removed, so then it looks as if the task was created after the delete, so the the delete basically kicks in when the select happens.

Comment: Now it is of course possible that another thread makes a select for a task and then another one to get one of these tasks, assuming these are still there, but that is possible with raw SQL as well, unless we have of course proper locking or isolation levels.